# I'm trying to make an until loop stop once I get a result

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
cd  /root/.OceanVieW

keyword=$( cat oceanview.conf |grep "seaworld" |cut -d "=" -f2);
until [ ${#keyword} -gt 1 ] ; do sleep 30
 cat oceanview.conf |grep "seaworld" |cut -d "=" -f2 ;
 done
```

The loop doesn't stop, it keeps going on. I want it to stop once I get a result.

Comment: The loop continues based on the value of `$keyword`, and `$keyword` never changes within the loop.

Comment: suppose the value of $keyword could vary between 0-30 , i want to keep the loop going till it get the value , if it's 0 then it keeps going till value changes then quit script , this code done exactly what i wanted but even after i get a result the the script keeps going i want to quit the script

Comment: *First* you assign something to `$keyword`; this only happens once. *Then* you run the loop, and you never change `$keyword` again.

Comment: i have assign a value to keyword and still script keeps going could you right a code

Comment: Once again: You only assign a value *before* the loop. `$keyword` *never* changes.

Comment: i got that thanks , how should i put it so that it works

Answer (score 1):

Simplification, (as per [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791049/im-trying-to-make-an-until-loop-stop-once-i-get-a-result/52799925?noredirect=1#comment92513085_52791049)), loop until `seaworld=0` is not found:

```
until grep -m 1 -vq '^seaworld=0$'  oceanview.conf ; do 
    sleep 30
done
```

If verbose output is needed, (a running list of numbers, which would all be `0` except the last one tested), try:

```
until grep -m 1  -v '^seaworld=0$'  oceanview.conf ; do 
    sleep 30
done | cut -d "=" -f2
```

If that's *too* verbose, then right after the `-f2` append `| uniq -c`, to show a count of `0`s, and the final number, printed after the loop completes.

Comment: @Biffen, Thanks, totally missed that.  See revised answer.